# How to test if my jradiomenubutton it's the value that i wanted

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, return, jradiobutton

What are the best way to test my return value if its the value that i selected, Somehow i'm stuck with the concept on how to get the value selected...

what my function does right now ,its that i added all the button that i wanted in my GUI and i return the value menu based on the button that i clicked.

```
private JMenu getOrdreMenu(){

    JMenu menu = new JMenu(MENU_ORDRE_TITLE);
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    JRadioButtonMenuItem item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_NSEQC);
             item.setSelected(true);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_NSEQD);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_FORMEC);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_FORMED);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_TYPENORMAL);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_TYPEINVERSE);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_DISTANCEC);
    group.add(item);
    menu.add(item);

    add(menu);
    return menu;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "What are the best way to test my return value if its the value that i selected, Somehow i'm stuck with the concept on how to get the value selected.."

Since they're in a `ButtonGroup` you don't need to check if one is selected. Every time one *is* selected, it will be the *only* one selected. So all you need to do is add an `ActionListener`

You don't seem to ever add a listener to the menu items. See this example, where I add a listener

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RadioMenus {

    private static final String MENU_ORDRE_TITLE = "Tilte";
    private static final String MENU_ORDRE_NSEQC = "NSEQC";
    private static final String MENU_ORDRE_NSEQD = "NSEQD";
    private static final String MENU_ORDRE_FORMEC = "FORMEC";

    public RadioMenus() {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        menubar.add(getOrdreMenu());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new RadioMenus();
            }
        });
    }

    private JMenu getOrdreMenu() {
        MyMenuListener listener = new MyMenuListener();

        JMenu menu = new JMenu(MENU_ORDRE_TITLE);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        JRadioButtonMenuItem item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_NSEQC);
        item.addActionListener(listener);
        group.add(item);
        menu.add(item);

        JRadioButtonMenuItem item1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_NSEQD);
        item1.addActionListener(listener);
        group.add(item1);
        menu.add(item1);

        JRadioButtonMenuItem item2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(MENU_ORDRE_FORMEC);
        item2.addActionListener(listener);
        group.add(item2);
        menu.add(item2);

        return menu;
    }

    public class MyMenuListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRadioButtonMenuItem menuItem = (JRadioButtonMenuItem)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(menuItem.getActionCommand());
        }
    }
}
```